# ¿Error 10 en la llamada al sistema wait?

Tags: c, linux

estoy escribiendo un pequeño programa que crea 5 procesos hijos, cada proceso hijo escribe por pantalla su pid y termina. El proceso padre se debe quedar a la espera y notificar por pantalla cada vez que un proceso termine además de especificar cuántos procesos quedan activos.

El código que he escrito es el siguiente

```
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>  
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int childpid=0;
    int n_hijos = 5;
    int estado;
    pid_t pid_aux = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_hijos; i++)
    {
        if(childpid == 0)
        {
            if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
            {
                printf("\nError %d en fork",errno);                                                                         
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    if(childpid != 0)
    {
        printf("Soy el hijo %d\n",getpid());
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    while(childpid == 0 && n_hijos > 0)
    {
        pid_aux = wait(&estado);
        if(pid_aux == -1)
        {
            printf("\nError %d en wait",errno);                                     
        }
        printf("\nAcaba de finalizar mi hijo con PID %d",pid_aux);
        n_hijos--;
        printf("\nSolo me quedan %d hijos vivos",n_hijos);
        
    }

    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

El problema es que la variable pid_aux del bucle siempre vale -1 y la variable errno vale 10.

[image: Ejecución del código]

He buscado que quiere decir errno 10 en la llamada la sistema wait, pero no lo encuentro y no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: usa `perror("en wait()")` cuando te retorne -1. Así, en vez del número de error verás un mensaje de texto que lo explica.

Comment: Aparentemente 10 es el error ECHILD que significa que el proceso no tiene ningún hijo por el que esperar. Creo que el error se produce porque estás llamando a `wait()` dentro de los hijos, ya que tienes mal la condición que discrimina si es padre o hijo. `fork()` retorna 0 en el hijo, y !=0 en el padre.

Comment: Es cierto era eso ya esta todo arreglado, muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como me comentaron por aquí lo que ocurre es que el error 10 corresponde a ECHILD (el proceso no tiene ningún hijo), se producía porque estaba llamando a wait() dentro de los hijos, ya que tenía mal la condición que discrimina si es padre o hijo. El código arreglado es el siguiente:

```
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>  
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int childpid=1;
    int n_hijos = 5;
    int estado;
    pid_t pid_aux = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_hijos; i++)
    {
        if(childpid != 0)
        {
            if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
            {
                printf("\nError %d en fork",errno);                                                                         
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
        printf("Soy el hijo %d\n",getpid());
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    while(childpid != 0 && n_hijos > 0)
    {
        pid_aux = wait(&estado);
        if(pid_aux == -1)
        {
            perror("En wait()");                                        
        }
        printf("\nAcaba de finalizar mi hijo con PID %d",pid_aux);
        n_hijos--;
        printf("\nSolo me quedan %d hijos vivos",n_hijos);
        
    }

    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda marcarla como aceptada en un rato (o mañana? no recuerdo el tiempo de espera). Gracias por compartir la pregunta y la respuesta :)